# Is there any function for adding timestamp to our message before storing in cassandra using kafka-cassandra sink connector?

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, fluentd

I'm setting up my logserver. I'm forwarding logs using Fluentd to Kafka and then storing them in Cassandra for later use. For this I'm using kafka-cassandra sink connector. I have to store data chronologically for which I need to add timestamp to my messages in cassandra. How can this be done?

Datamountaineer connector uses kcql which i think doesn't support inserting timestamp to a log.

My connector configuration is as follows:

```
name=cassandra-sink
connector.class=com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=test_AF1
connect.cassandra.kcql=INSERT INTO test_event1 SELECT now() as id, message as msg FROM test_AF1 TIMESTAMP=sys_time()
connect.cassandra.port=9042
connect.cassandra.contact.points=localhost
connect.cassandra.key.space=demo
```

Answer (score 2):

Kafka Connect's Single Message Transform can do this. Here's an example:

```
{
  "connector.class": "com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraSinkConnector",
  "topics": "test_AF1",
…
  "transforms": "addTS",
  "transforms.addTS.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
  "transforms.addTS.timestamp.field": "op_ts"
}'
```

This adds a field to the message payload called `op_ts` with the timestamp of the Kafka message.

I don't know how this interacts with KCQL; you might want to check out the other two Cassandra sinks that I'm aware of:

- https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-cassandra
- https://www.confluent.io/hub/datastax/kafka-connect-dse

Comment: The problem with using confluent connectors is that they aren't free tools. Confluent provides a 30-day trial version, upon expiry of which, i'll have to pay some amount for using them in future. This is the only reason that i'm using the connector from lenses.io because they are free.